# A question from my final exam

Tags: integration, limits

Today I had the final exam of the lesson Mathematics I. There was a question that I want to know if I solved correctly the following limit.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{0^2+n^2} + \frac{n}{1^2+n^2} + \frac{n}{2^2+n^2} + \dots + \frac{n}{(n-1)^2+n^2}\right)$$

By using the summation symbol and integral method, I found the answer $\pi/4$ . Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes ... its the correct answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is correct; however, because you have only described your method of solution rather than shown it, it is not possible at this time to confirm whether or not your actual computation was without methodological or conceptual flaws.  We can only say that the value of the quantity you wrote is in fact $\pi/4$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you and everybody else. Since I don't know how to write math symbols here, let me describe my solution with letters. I converted the limit into an definite integral which goes from 0 to 1 and is (1 / (x^2+1))dx. Integration gave me arctan function. And I found the answer --> arctan1 - arctan 0 = pi/4 .